# specific rows style for in custom list table using WP_List_Table

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, wp-list-table

I am building a custom WordPress plugin where I create a custom list table for entities in a custom database table, extending the WP_List_Table class.

Everything works as expected but I want to style each row based on the value of a specific column of the row that is returned from the DB.

The iteration of the columns for each row happens inside the column_default() function:

```
/**
 * Render a column when no column specific method exists.
 *
 * @param array $item
 * @param string $column_name
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function column_default( $item, $column_name ) {
    
    switch ( $column_name ) {           
        case 'id':
            return $item[$column_name];
        default:
          return $item[$column_name];
    }
}
```

For example:

If the viw_status column of the current item that is printed on the list table equals 1 `($item['viw_status '] == 1)`, the current item's row must have green background color otherwise grey something.

Is there a any way to apply a custom css class to a row based on the values of its columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends where you want to apply your custom css class.

## CSS class for table row

If you want to add the custom class to the `<tr>` element, I recommend to overwrite the function `single_row` like so:

```
public function single_row( $item ) {
    $cssClass = ($item['view_status '] == 1) ? 'make-it-green' : 'make-it-grey';
    echo '<tr class="'.$cssClass.'">';
    $this->single_row_columns( $item );
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

## CSS class for table cell

Use the `column_{column name}` functions like you have outlined it with `column_default` and put a HTML tag as a wrapper within the cell. For example a `span` element:

```
public function column_default( $item, $column_name ) {
    $cssClass = ($item['view_status '] == 1) ? 'make-it-green' : 'make-it-grey';
    switch ( $column_name ) {           
        case 'id':
            return '<span class="'.$cssClass.'">'.$item[$column_name].'</span>';
        default:
          return $item[$column_name];
    }
}
```

Comment: This was really helpful. Thanks!